# Prepose the reproduction of video advertises to the requested content

Tags: ads

here is the scenario:

- Scott comes on my website and wants to read some "precious lines of text"
- Clicks a link that redirect him to a page that **hides the "precious lines of text"**
- Before he can visualize the "precious lines of text" a **video advertisement** must be entirely reproduced
- So, a **third party video player** reproduces an advertise
- Maybe the video player checks with its mechanisms if Scott is seeing the ad
- At the end of the reproduction a script **callback** tells to my page that the ad has been consumed
- The "precious lines of text" are shown
- At the end of the month I **get paid** for each ad visualization

I want to obtain something like this using some kind of service like "AdSense for videos"...

Does anyone knows any service that can allow me to do this or something similar?

thanks

**EDIT:**

I'm looking for an AD provider like Google that will:

1. provide a free video player to reproduce ADs once included in my page
2. provide player API to obtain a callback
3. pay for each video AD reproductions

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a service for this. You'll just need to modify your website:

1. Adjust your links so that they work as you described
2. Adjust your page code so that the user sees a video player first and the "precious lines of text" are hidden
3. You'll need a video player that can work with ads and provides an API that would allow your to catch to moment when the video is completed i.e. check out [jwplayer](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/javascript-api-reference/#advertising)
4. Once you catch the completion event in your js code you'll need to show the "precious lines of text"

So your task boils down to js coding and picking the right video player

Comment: You suggest to modify my website in the same way is described in the scenario, and this is not helpfull. Maybe I'm not been clear so I edited for clarification. 
**Jwplayer is near to the solution _but it's not free_**. Thanks.